# What is the parent class of a generated ViewBinding?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to DRY up my code and I have a couple activities which use the same blocks of code which I want to move into a method in the parent activity. The problem is that this code uses generated ViewBindings which are unique classes, and I can't figure out what the parent class is in order to use it as a method parameter.

For example, this code is in two different activities and the only difference is that in one activity binding = Activity1Binding, in the other one it's Activity2Binding. They share some views with the same IDs.

```
binding.noteTitleTV.setOnClickListener { changeTitle() }
binding.deleteModalLayout.setOnClickListener { binding.deleteModalLayout.visibility = View.GONE }
binding.cancelDeleteButton.setOnClickListener { binding.deleteModalLayout.visibility = View.GONE }
binding.confirmDeleteButton.setOnClickListener { onDeleteNoteClicked() }
```

I would like to implement something like this in the parent activity to prevent duplicate code, if that's possible:

```
fun setUp(binding: [BINDING PARENT CLASS]) {
  binding.noteTitleTV.setOnClickListener { changeTitle() }
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated classes extend the Object class (java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

The binding class inherits from ViewDataBinding, so you could do this (Kotlin code)

```
fun setUp(binding: ViewDataBinding) {
   when(binding){
      is Activity1Binding -> { (binding as Activity1Binding).noteTitelTV.setOnClickListner{ changeTitle() } }  
      is Activity2Binding -> { (binding as Activity2Binding).noteTitelTV.setOnClickListner{ changeTitle() } }  
   }
   // etc
}
```

I don't know that it could get more "generic" than that as you don't control the generated classes. But that would at least allow you to place all the code in a single class as you suggested. I use a similar approach in that I have an lateinit instance of all of my generated binding classes and just set which is active based on the passed variable and use that instance name so i don't have to keep typing as.

ex:

```
private lateinit var itemBinding : GroceryItemBinding
private lateinit var maintItemBinding : GroceryItemMaintBinding
private lateinit var compareItemBinding : GroceryItemCompareBinding
private lateinit var priceItemBinding : GroceryItemPriceBinding
private lateinit var adItemBinding : GroceryItemAdBinding
```

```
when(viewBinding){ 
   is GroceryItemMaintBinding -> {
      maintItemBinding = viewBinding as GroceryItemMaintBinding
      maintItemBinding.groceryItem = gi
      maintItemBinding.groceryItemImage.setOnClickListener { ... }
      ......
   }
   is GroceryItemBinding -> {
      itemBinding = viewBinding as GroceryItemBinding
   }
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewBinding can create by `bind(view)`, so you can create a base class like this:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: Activity1Binding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val view = createContentView()
        // create ViewBinding
        binding = Activity1Binding.bind(view)
    }

    // create view by subclass
    abstract fun createContentView(): View

    fun setTextViewTitle(text: CharSequence) {
        binding.tvTitle.text = text
    }
}
```

this is the content of `Activity1Binding#bind()`:

```java
  @NonNull
  public static ActivityMainBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    // The body of this method is generated in a way you would not otherwise write.
    // This is done to optimize the compiled bytecode for size and performance.
    int id;
    missingId: {
      id = R.id.layout;
      FinanceLabelLayout layout = rootView.findViewById(id);
      if (layout == null) {
        break missingId;
      }

      return new ActivityMainBinding((ConstraintLayout) rootView, layout);
    }
    String missingId = rootView.getResources().getResourceName(id);
    throw new NullPointerException("Missing required view with ID: ".concat(missingId));
  }
```

But this is not recommended.

**This is not type safe.**